# Arduino Mega Multi Serial String

Tags: string, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

I've tried to find an answer in other places, but without success.. I hope here can someone can help me..

I'll try to simplify my question as I can:
Well.. **Is it possible to compound a string from multiple UARTs, than send that over another ?**

I use Serial2 to comunicate with an Attiny, and Serial1 is wired to a Bluetooth module.

Is there any chances to  wait for data from attiny, add the received data to the string and then pass it over bluetooth ?

Something like this Attiny => Attiny + Arduino Mega Results ~> bluetooth ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's posible. You can take a look for [serialEvent](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent) reference and its [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent). You can do this for more Serials and print it to the right destination.

Comment: Thanks very much, works perfect, is a step forward in my project :)